# How to retrieve list with max, offset and sort parameters with Grails ORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a grails application with `User` and `Group` domain objects. The `User` has many `Group` objects and the `Group` object contains many `User` objects:

```
class User implements Serializable {

    static constraints = {
        usergroups nullable: true
    }

    static mapping = {
        usergroups cascade: 'all-delete-orphan'
    }

    static hasMany = [
        usergroups: Group
    ]

    static mappedBy = [
        usergroups : "creator"
    ]
}

class Group {

    static belongsTo = [
        creator : User
    ]

    static hasMany = [
        members : User
    ]

    static constraints = {
        creator nullable: false
        members nullable: true, maxSize: 100
    }
}
```

Given a `Group` object, can I retrieve the members with `max`, `offset` and `sortBy` parameters? Something like...

```
def members = User.where {
   /* how to specify only the users in 'group.members'? */
}.list(
  max: max, 
  offset: offset, 
  sortBy : sortBy
);
```

**Edit**

To try and fix the problem I have altered the `User` class to contain a `joinedgroups` field...

```
class User implements Serializable {

    static constraints = {
        usergroups nullable: true
        joinedgroups nullable: true
    }

    static mapping = {
        usergroups cascade: 'all-delete-orphan'
    }

    static hasMany = [
        usergroups: Group
        joinedgroups: Group
    ]

    static mappedBy = [
        usergroups : "creator",
        joinedgroups : "creator" // if I don't add this Grails complains there is no owner defined between domain classes User and Group. 
    ]
}
```

But now when I try to retrieve all the User's `usergroup` objects in another part of my application only a single usergroup is returned...

```
    def groups = Group.where {
        creator.id == user.id
    }.list(max: max, offset: offset, sort: sortBy); // should return 3 groups but now only returns 1
```

This query worked before so maybe adding the extra `mappedby` entry in `User` has caused the problem. Is the new `mappedby` field in `User` incorrect?

Comment: Have you tried with `static mappedBy = [usergroups : "creator", joinedgroups : "members"]`?

Comment: I have indeed, thanks. I get an error saying 'no owner defined between domain classes User and Group'. I can get it working though if I do `static mappedby = [usergroups : "creator", joinedgroups : "none"]`. I don't know why that works to be honest (or if that's going to cause another problem later).

Comment: If the answer is correct for your initial question, accept them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the groups that contains a user are saved in the `usergroups` field, you could use:

```
def query = User.where {
    usergroups { id == myGroup.id }
}

def users = query.list(max: 10, offset: 0, sort : "id")
```

Comment: Thanks but that only seems to retrieve the `User` who is the creator of the Group (i.e. who created `myGroup.id`). I'm guessing it queries the `usergroups` of each `User` and checks whether that usergroup is the same as `myGroup`?

Comment: Why don't you add another field in User called joinedGroups so you can use this query? I think that this field is a natural way for mapping this situations. In my projects I use this structure to solve similar problems.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but adding a joinedgroups field broke another part of the application. Could you have a look at the edit above? Perhaps it is a problem with how the `User` is now defined?